# Show *ngFor items one by one Ionic 4

Tags: angular, angular7, ionic4

I have a JSON object and I want to show the items one by one. When I use the Angular `*ngFor` all the items show on the screen. I want to show the first one and when I click the button show the next one until the last. I have tried using Angular `*ngIf` but I failed.

```html
<ion-header>
 <ion-toolbar>
  <ion-buttons slot="start">
  <ion-icon size="large" color="warning" name="arrow-round-back" 
  (click)="abort()"></ion-icon>
  </ion-buttons>
 <ion-title></ion-title>
 </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>    
<ion-card *ngFor="let w of warmup;">
 <ion-card-header>
  <ion-card-title>
    {{w.title}}
  </ion-card-title>
  <ion-card-content>
    <img src="{{w.url}}">
  </ion-card-content>
</ion-card-header>
<ion-button slot="end" size="small" (click)="done">DONE</ion-button>
</ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

You can also see an image of what I mean:

[image]

Comment: you can use ion-slides

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use angular slicePipe

https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

create a `noOfItem = 1` in your component ts

```
*ngFor="let w of warmup | slice:0:noOfItem"
```

Then control the `noOfItem` based on your logic

Comment: I set the noOfitems value at 1.
I added the slice on the ngFor:

 <ion-card *ngFor="let w of warmup | slice:noOfItem-1:noOfItem">

And the done method is like this:

done(){
    if(this.noOfItem < this.warmup.length){
      this.noOfItem += 1;
    } else {
      console.log('END OF DAY 1')
    }

It works Perfectly !Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to maintain another array which will hold the templates.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let w of warmupTemp;" [w]="w"></<ion-card>
```

And your ts file will be:

```
warmpup = []; // actual data array
warmupTemp= []; // template array
index = 0;
addWarmUp() {
    this.warmupTemp.push(warmup[index]);
    index++;
}
```